# Why is my ggplot going dot to dot instead of plotting a line of regression?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I want a line of regression to be plotted showing herbivorous damage (%) as a function of distance from the ecotone. But as you can see it is joining all the data points together.

Here is the plot:
[image: Plot]

Here is the code:

```
#plotting herbivory as a function of distance from the ecotone
# Get fitted values for our model 
model_fit <- predict(object = herb.mod, se.fit = T)
# Add these predictions to our original data frame, in a column called fit
leaf.data$fit <- model_fit$fit
# We can then work out the upper and lower bounds of our confidence intervals, adding them to separate columns
leaf.data$upper <- model_fit$fit  + 2 * model_fit$se
leaf.data$lower <- model_fit$fit  - 2 * model_fit$se

ggplot(data=leaf.data)+
  geom_point(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = mean.herbivory, col=transect))+
  # add a line for model fit
  geom_line(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = mean.herbivory), size=1.0)+
  # add a ribbon showing the CIs
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha=0.25)+
  # add a title 
  ggtitle("Herbivorous Damage as a Function of Distance from an Ecotone")+
  theme_light()
```

Comment: Do `geom_smooth(method = 'lm')` in order to get linear regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to draw a line through the means, and not the individual points, so you can either use geom_smooth(), you plot through the mean of your predictions:

```
set.seed(111)
leaf.data = data.frame(distance.from.ecotone=rep(seq(5,22.5,by=2.5),each=5))
leaf.data$mean.herbivory = -3*leaf.data$distance.from.ecotone + rnorm(nrow(leaf.data),0,3) + 80
leaf.data$transect = rep(c("One","Two"),each=5,times=4)

herb.mod = lm(mean.herbivory~distance.from.ecotone,data=leaf.data)
model_fit <- predict(object = herb.mod, se.fit = T)
leaf.data$fit <- model_fit$fit
leaf.data$upper <- model_fit$fit  + 2 * model_fit$se
leaf.data$lower <- model_fit$fit  - 2 * model_fit$se
```

This will work:

```
ggplot(data=leaf.data)+
geom_point(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = mean.herbivory, col=transect))+
geom_line(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = fit), size=1.0)+
geom_ribbon(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha=0.25)
```

[image]

Note that your confidence intervals are also duplicated:

```
tail(leaf.data)
   distance.from.ecotone mean.herbivory transect      fit    upper     lower
35                  20.0      13.202012      One 19.05008 20.68734 17.412828
36                  22.5      15.988981      Two 11.55215 13.57185  9.532456
37                  22.5      12.151535      Two 11.55215 13.57185  9.532456
38                  22.5      13.502768      Two 11.55215 13.57185  9.532456
39                  22.5      10.637426      Two 11.55215 13.57185  9.532456
40                  22.5       8.570465      Two 11.55215 13.57185  9.532456
```

Maybe makes more sense to create a separate data.frame for prediction, like:

```
pred = data.frame(distance.from.ecotone = 5:23)
model_fit <- predict(herb.mod, pred,se.fit = T)
pred$fit <- model_fit$fit
pred$upper <- model_fit$fit  + 2 * model_fit$se
pred$lower <- model_fit$fit  - 2 * model_fit$se

ggplot(data=leaf.data)+
geom_point(aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = mean.herbivory, col=transect))+
geom_line(data=pred,aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, y = fit), size=1.0)+
geom_ribbon(data=pred,aes(x = distance.from.ecotone, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha=0.25)
```